# Is there a way to find out how close two keyboard keys are close to each other?

Tags: javascript

I want to draw some simple figures using characters' position on the keyboard. You can find out character key code, but for example a and s are neighbours, but their codes are 65 and 83, which doesn't say at all that they are close. Ideally they would be 65 and 66. I could create a characters two-dimensional array for every keyboard, but that is a lot of manual work.

The simple picture on the keyboard is used to memorise the password easier.

Comment: if you mean with ASCII value yes but if you mean physically on keyboard so go to sleep

Comment: That is a lot of work, but that is the only way. You can try to google for some ready snippets for this probably.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is doable. Not only have I never seen anything that would make this doable, I think you would run into problems for the following reason:

Different keyboards from different countries have different setups.

Just an example: In Spain they have the character `Ñ` which offsets the keys.

Comment: But that special symbol still has a particular key on the non qerty spanish keyboard. What do you mean by offsets the keys?

Comment: @LukasGreblikas I'm thinking that if you're trying to draw a keyboard based on position of keys, you could never have a standard keyboard image because every keyboard is different. You can't get the "position" of a key on a keyboard using javascript, that's impossible. So you would then have to have set positions for each key (which won't work, see answer).

Comment: Well I assume that the same user most of the time uses one keyboard (but it could be any keyboard) so the simple picture still stays the same if user doesn't change the keyboard.